# Drawing from a specific x-axis value to a line intersection then to y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, how to automate the process of drawing from a specific x-axis point up to the intersection to a line, then to the y-axis.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{2.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xlab}{2006}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{5}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*\xn+2,0);
\node at (\incrmntx*\xn+2,\incrmnty*\yn-.4) (endx){};% to compensate for the shift of the x-axis labels, and to draw short from the end of the y-axis 
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*\yn);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmntx*.4cm, yshift=0cm]% to shift the x-axis labels
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\xlab+(1*\x))]in {0,...,\xn}{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.68cm] {\footnotesize \aff} -- +(-90:.2);}
\end{scope}
\draw[blue!40!black, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty) -- (endx.center);
\draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed] (\incrmntx*\xn+.8,0) --+(90:4.26cm) node (aa){} -| (aa.center-|0,0) node [black, xshift=-1cm, yshift=.06cm] {2011 value};
\draw[red!40!black, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty) -- (endx.center);
\draw[red!80!white, thick, dashed] (\incrmntx*\xn-3.2,0) --+(90:3.7cm) node (bb){} -| (bb.center-|0,0) node [black, xshift=-1cm, yshift=.06cm] {2009 value};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the plots are not always straight lines, I recommend using the `intersections` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{2.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xlab}{2006}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{5}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*\xn+2,0);
  \node at (\incrmntx*\xn+2,\incrmnty*\yn-.4) (endx){};% to compensate for the shift of the x-axis labels, and to draw short from the end of the y-axis 
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*\yn);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmntx*.4cm, yshift=0cm]% to shift the x-axis labels
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\xlab+(1*\x))]
  in {0,...,\xn}{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) 
  node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.68cm,font=\footnotesize] {\aff} -- +(-90:.2);}
  \end{scope}
  \draw[blue!40!black, line width=.4mm,name path=blue plot] (-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty) -- (endx.center);
  \path[overlay,name path=vert-1] (\incrmntx*\xn+.8,0) -- ++(0,10);
  \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed,name intersections={of=blue plot and vert-1,
  by=i1}] (\incrmntx*\xn+.8,0) |- (i1 -|0,0) node [black, left] {2011 value};
  \draw[red!40!black, line width=.4mm,name path=red plot] (-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty) -- (endx.center);
  \path[overlay,name path=vert-2] (\incrmntx*\xn-3.2,0) -- ++(0,10);
  \draw[red!80!white, thick, dashed,name intersections={of=red plot and vert-2,
  by=i2}] (\incrmntx*\xn-3.2,0) |- (i2 -|0,0) 
  node [black,left] {2009 value};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, however, you are dealing with straight lines, you could work with the `calc` library instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{2.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xlab}{2006}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{5}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*\xn+2,0);
  \node at (\incrmntx*\xn+2,\incrmnty*\yn-.4) (endx){};% to compensate for the shift of the x-axis labels, and to draw short from the end of the y-axis 
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*\yn);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmntx*.4cm, yshift=0cm]% to shift the x-axis labels
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\xlab+(1*\x))]
  in {0,...,\xn}{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) 
  node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.68cm,font=\footnotesize] {\aff} -- +(-90:.2);}
  \end{scope}
  \draw[blue!40!black, line width=.4mm] 
  (-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty) coordinate(blue-start) -- (endx.center);
  \path (intersection cs:first line={(blue-start) -- (endx.center)},
  second line={(\incrmntx*\xn+.8,0)--(\incrmntx*\xn+.8,10)}) coordinate (i1);
  \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed] (\incrmntx*\xn+.8,0) |- (i1 -|0,0) node [black, left] {2011 value};
  \draw[red!40!black, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty) 
  coordinate(red-start)-- (endx.center);
  \path (intersection cs:first line={(red-start) -- (endx.center)},
  second line={(\incrmntx*\xn-3.2,0)--(\incrmntx*\xn-3.2,10)}) coordinate (i2);
  \draw[red!80!white, thick, dashed] (\incrmntx*\xn-3.2,0) |- (i2 -|0,0) 
  node [black,left] {2009 value};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This leads to the same output.

The common strategy is to determine the intersections between the plots and vertical lines that start at the specified x coordinates. These intersections are called `i1` and `i2` in both examples. And then one can use them in

```
 \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed] (\incrmntx*\xn+.8,0) |- (i1 -|0,0) node [black, left] {2011 value};
```

and

```
  \draw[red!40!black, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty) 
  coordinate(red-start)-- (endx.center);
```

respectively, to draw the vertical and then horizontal lines and place the nodes left of them.

The calc example can be made a style.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape,-|/.style args={of #1 at #2}{%
insert path={(intersection cs:first line={#1},second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) 
coordinate (aux) (#2,0) |- (0,0|-aux) }},vert/.style args={of #1 at #2}{%
insert path={(#2,0) 
-- (intersection cs:first line={#1},second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) }}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{2.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xlab}{2006}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{5}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*\xn+2,0);
  \node at (\incrmntx*\xn+2,\incrmnty*\yn-.4) (endx){};% to compensate for the shift of the x-axis labels, and to draw short from the end of the y-axis 
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*\yn);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=\incrmntx*.4cm, yshift=0cm]% to shift the x-axis labels
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\xlab+(1*\x))]
  in {0,...,\xn}{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) 
  node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.68cm,font=\footnotesize] {\aff} -- +(-90:.2);}
  \end{scope}
  \draw[blue!40!black, line width=.4mm] 
  (-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty) -- (endx.center);
  \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed,
  -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn+.8}}]
  node [black, left] {2011 value};
  \draw[red!40!black, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty) -- (endx.center);  
  \draw[red!80!white, thick, dashed,
  -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-3.2}}]  
  node[black,left] {2009 value};
  \draw[violet!80!white, thick, dashed,
  vert={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at 
  {\incrmntx*\xn-2}}]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with which the whole story boils down to

```
\draw[red!80!white, thick, dashed,
  -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,2.5*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-3.2}}]  
  node[black,left] {2009 value};
```

This contains an additional style `vert` that can be used

```
\draw[violet!80!white, thick, dashed,
  vert={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at 
  {\incrmntx*\xn-2}}];
```

[image]

Comment: @marmotThank you very very much for your time for this very nice answer and the provided explanation.

Comment: @Hany You're welcome. (I made the calc example a style which may simplify matters if you have many of those.)

Comment: @marmotJust one comment in your edited answer, for the first line you mentioned coordinate(blue-start); but for the second line you did not say coordinate(red-start). Should I remove this coordinate(blue-start)

Comment: @Hany Good catch! `coordinate(blue-start)` was not needed in the last code.

Comment: @marmotThank you very much. I always appreciate your concern and time.

Comment: @marmotI am sorry to bother you again. I just want the code to draw a line from x-axis to the intersection only, without drawing to the y-axis, how to modify this command: \draw[violet!80!white, thick, dashed, -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-3.2}}];

Comment: @Hany I added a new style called `vert` to the example.

Comment: @marmotThank you very much. Does your final addition work for straight and non- straight lines, or should I use the first code for non-straight line.

Comment: @Hany Everything but the very first code does only work for straight lines. The first code (which loads `intersections`) works with curves, too.

Comment: @marmotThank you. So for curves I will use the first code only.