# Modifying the code for Drawing from a specific x-axis value to a line intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code from the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476096/drawing-from-a-specific-x-axis-value-to-a-line-intersection-then-to-y-axis)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape, -|/.style args={of #1 at #2}{insert path={(intersection cs:first line={#1}, second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) coordinate (aux) (#2,0) |- (0,0|-aux) }}, vert/.style args={of #1 at #2}{insert path={(#2,0) -- (intersection cs:first line={#1}, second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) }}]% this is used when drawing 2 lines to intersect with
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{2.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xlab}{2006}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{5}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*\xn+\incrmntx*1,0);
\node at (\incrmntx*\xn+\incrmntx*1,\incrmnty*\yn-.4) (endx){};
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*\yn);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\xlab+(1*\x))] in {0,...,\xn}{\draw [black!40!white] (\incrmntx*\x+\incrmntx*.4,0) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.68cm, font=\footnotesize] {\aff} -- +(-90:.2);}
\end{scope}
\draw[blue!40!black, densely dashed, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty) node [black, left, yshift=-.06cm] {Intercept} -- (endx.center);
\draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed, -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn+\incrmntx*.4}}] node [black, left, yshift=.06cm] {2011 value};
\draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed, -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-2+\incrmntx*.4}}] node [black, left, yshift=-.06cm] {2010 value};
\draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed, vert={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-4+\incrmntx*.4}}];
\draw[red!80!white, thick] (\incrmntx*\xn-7+\incrmntx*.4,2.58*\incrmnty) -- (\incrmntx*\xn-10+\incrmntx*.4,2.58*\incrmnty) node [black, xshift=.6cm, yshift=.3cm] {Slope} -- +(-90:.82cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How to make the following modifications:

1. Modifying the style to draw only one oblique line, instead of two
2. Drawing the red line from the intersection of the specified location with the oblique line (a point in between 2007 and 2008), to the final specified location (at 2006)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a style `hat` to address the second point. The first point I do, unfortunately, not understand. What do you mean by "draw only one oblique line, instead of two", i.e. which two lines are you referring to?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape, 
  -|/.style args={of #1 at #2}{insert path={(intersection cs:first line={#1}, second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) coordinate (aux) (#2,0) |- (0,0|-aux) }}, 
  vert/.style args={of #1 at #2}{insert path={(#2,0) -- (intersection cs:first
  line={#1}, second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) }},
  hat/.style args={of #1 at #2 and #3}{insert path={%
  (intersection cs:first line={#1}, second line={(#2,0)--(#2,10)}) |-
  (intersection cs:first line={#1}, second line={(#3,0)--(#3,10)}) 
  }}
 ]% this is used when drawing 2 lines to intersect with
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{2.}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xlab}{2006}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{5}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*\xn+\incrmntx*1,0);
  \node at (\incrmntx*\xn+\incrmntx*1,\incrmnty*\yn-.4) (endx){};
  \draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*\yn);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \aff using int(\xlab+(1*\x))] in {0,...,\xn}{\draw [black!40!white] (\incrmntx*\x+\incrmntx*.4,0) node [black, xshift=0cm, yshift=-.68cm, font=\footnotesize] {\aff} -- +(-90:.2);}
 \end{scope}
  \draw[blue!40!black, densely dashed, line width=.4mm] (-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty) node [black, left, yshift=-.06cm] {Intercept} -- (endx.center);
  \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed, -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn+\incrmntx*.4}}] node [black, left, yshift=.06cm] {2011 value};
  \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed, -|={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-2+\incrmntx*.4}}] node [black, left, yshift=-.06cm] {2010 value};
  \draw[blue!80!white, thick, dashed, vert={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)} at {\incrmntx*\xn-4+\incrmntx*.4}}];
  \draw[red!80!white, thick,hat={of {(-.1*\incrmntx,1.56*\incrmnty)--(endx.center)}
   at {\incrmntx*\xn-10+\incrmntx*.4} and {\incrmntx*\xn-7+\incrmntx*.4}}]
   node[black,pos=0.55,above right]{Slope};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmotThank you. I am referring to my previous question where there are 2 lines (blue and red), for which you defined cs:first line={#1}, second line=

Comment: @marmotI figured out your code, I misunderstood it when I asked about (Modifying the style to draw only one oblique line, instead of two). Thank you very much for your time, answer and modification.