# Tikz: Perpendicular FROM a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

With `tikz-pgf`, I can draw a perpendicular from a point to a line. Is there a robust method to draw a perpendicular *from* a point? For example, in the following code, say I want to raise a perpendicular, from a specific point on line `BC` outwards.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (8,0);

    \draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw[red] (B) -- ($(A)!(B)!(C)$);

    \node[label={below left:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
    \node[label={below right:$C$}] at (C) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You changed the position of the starting point in your question : so to draw from a point `P` on `BC` you can use `(P) -- ++({2/sqrt(13)},{3/sqrt(13)})` (or to for faster compile `(P) -- ++(0.5547001962252291,0.8320502943378437)`), or you can use as I said `calc` to draw `(P) -- ($(P)!1cm!90:(C)$)`.

Comment: @Kpym I edited it because in the given form the suggested approach was obvious. I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: Hmm! I was being a fool, again. Say the point on `BC` is the midpoint. I can simply define that coordinate as, say, `\coordinate (P) at ($(B)!0.5!(C)$)`. Then I can do, `\draw (P)--($(P)!0.5!90:(C)$)`.

Comment: @blackened or `\draw[red, thick] (P) -- ($(A)!(P)!(C)$);` as you already did for your line from B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just wrote such a style in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476098/121799). I slightly changed the syntax, so you need to say

```
\draw[blue,vert={of {(B)--(C)} at (3,0)}];
```

to draw a vertical line at `(3,0)` that goes all the way until it hits `BC`. And I added `vert outwards` which is just a wrapper of the distance modifiers (see section 13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers of the pgfmanual), and can be used as

```
    \draw[blue,vert outwards={from {($(B)!0.3!(C)$)} by 3cm on line to {(C)}}];
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[vert/.style args={of #1 at #2}{insert path={%
#2 -- (intersection cs:first
  line={#1}, second line={#2--($#2+(0,10)$)}) }},
vert outwards/.style args={from #1 by #2 on line to #3}{insert path={
#1 -- ($#1!#2!90:#3$)
}}]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,4);
    \coordinate (C) at (8,0);

    \draw(A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw[red] (B) -- ($(A)!(B)!(C)$);

    \node[label={below left:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[label={above:$B$}] at (B) {};
    \node[label={below right:$C$}] at (C) {};
    \draw[blue,vert={of {(B)--(C)} at (3,0)}];
    \draw[blue,vert outwards={from {($(B)!0.3!(C)$)} by 3cm on line to {(C)}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

if you willing to define specific point on line `(B)--(C)` with its relative position, than you can write your *mwe* as following simple solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label=below left:$A$]   (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above:$B$]        (B) at (2,4);
    \coordinate[label=below right:$C$]  (C) at (8,0);

    \draw(A)--(B)-- coordinate[pos=0.3] (aux) % <--- coordinate of the point
                    (C)--cycle;
    \draw[red] (aux) -- (aux |- A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, not tikz. I understand @hpekris's idea.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {.3,.5,.7}{
\begin{pspicture}[PointSymbol=none,linejoin=1](0,-1)(8,4)
\pnodes(0,0){A}(2,4){B}(8,0){C}(4,0){I}
\psline(A)(B)(C)(A)
\pstHomO[HomCoef=\i,PosAngle=75]{B}{C}[M]
\pstProjection[PosAngle=-90]{A}{C}{B}[H]
\pstProjection[PosAngle=-90]{A}{C}{M}[M']
\pcline(M)(M')
\pcline(B)(H)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good, please could you decrease the velocity of the animation :-)?

Answer (score 4):

*Answer to the first version of the question*

With `intersections` you can give a name to your triangle path, then build a "fake path" from (4,0) to a point after the intersection with the triangle (you don't need to calculate it exactly, see `name path=riga` and draw it to understand what I'm saying) and name it, then you can draw a line between the intersections with your triangle and your "fake path".

*Answer to the second version of the question*

If you want to start from a point on `BC`, you can use `\coordinate (P) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);` with any value you want instead of `.5` and do like you did for the line from `B` (see the thick red line in my MWE).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label={below left:$A$}] (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label={above:$B$}] (B) at (2,4);
    \coordinate[label={below right:$C$}] (C) at (8,0);

    \draw[name path=trian](A)  --(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw[red] (B) -- ($(A)!(B)!(C)$);
    \path [name path=riga] (4,0) -- ++(0,3);
    \path [name intersections={of=trian and riga}];
    \draw (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
    \coordinate (P) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);
    \draw[red, thick] (P) -- ($(A)!(P)!(C)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understood the question as OP want a line starting from som point on `BC` and going perpendicular to `BC` outward some distance. (ok now I see that the question has been edited).

Answer (score 3):

Another PSTricks solution just for comparison purposes.

I provide some possible tricks but you can remove the parts that you don't want.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{pspicture}(8,5)
\pstTriangle(1,1){A}(7,1){B}(3,4){C}
\psline(C)(C|A)
\pnode([nodesep=\i]{B}C){P}
\psline(P)(P|A)
\pnode([nodesep=\i,offset=\i]{B}C){Q}
\psline[linecolor=red](P)(Q)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]